# mongodb $unwind empty array

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

With this data:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("576948b4999274493425c08a"),
    "virustotal" : {
        "scan_id" : "4a6c3dfc6677a87aee84f4b629303c40bb9e1dda283a67236e49979f96864078-1465973544",
        "sha1" : "fd177b8c50b457dbec7cba56aeb10e9e38ebf72f",
        "resource" : "4a6c3dfc6677a87aee84f4b629303c40bb9e1dda283a67236e49979f96864078",
        "response_code" : 1,
        "scan_date" : "2016-06-15 06:52:24",
        "results" : [ 
            {
                "sig" : "Gen:Variant.Mikey.29601",
                "vendor" : "MicroWorld-eScan"
            }, 
            {
                "sig" : null,
                "vendor" : "nProtect"
            }, 
            {
                "sig" : null,
                "vendor" : "CAT-QuickHeal"
            }, 
            {
                "sig" : "HEUR/QVM07.1.0000.Malware.Gen",
                "vendor" : "Qihoo-360"
            }
        ]
    }
},
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5768f214999274362f714e8b"),
    "virustotal" : {
        "scan_id" : "3d283314da4f99f1a0b59af7dc1024df42c3139fd6d4d4fb4015524002b38391-1466529838",
        "sha1" : "fb865b8f0227e9097321182324c959106fcd8c27",
        "resource" : "3d283314da4f99f1a0b59af7dc1024df42c3139fd6d4d4fb4015524002b38391",
        "response_code" : 1,
        "scan_date" : "2016-06-21 17:23:58",
        "results" : [ 
            {
                "sig" : null,
                "vendor" : "Bkav"
            }, 
            {
                "sig" : null,
                "vendor" : "ahnlab"
            }, 
            {
                "sig" : null,
                "vendor" : "MicroWorld-eScan"
            }, 
            {
                "sig" : "Mal/DrodZp-A",
                "vendor" : "Qihoo-360"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

I'm trying to group by and count the vendor when sig is not null in order to obtain something like:

```
{
    "_id" : "Qihoo-360",
    "count" : 2
},
{
    "_id" : "MicroWorld-eScan",
    "count" : 1
},
{
    "_id" : "Bkav",
    "count" : 0
},
{
    "_id" : "CAT-QuickHeal",
    "count" : 0
}
```

At the moment with this code:

```
db.analysis.aggregate([ 
    { $unwind: "$virustotal.results"  },
    {
        $group : {
             _id : "$virustotal.results.vendor", 
             count : { $sum : 1 }
        }
    },
    { $sort : { count : -1 } }
])
```

I'm getting everything:

```
{
    "_id" : "Qihoo-360",
    "count" : 2
},
{
    "_id" : "MicroWorld-eScan",
    "count" : 2
},
{
    "_id" : "Bkav",
    "count" : 1
},
{
    "_id" : "CAT-QuickHeal",
    "count" : 1
}
```

How can I count 0 if the sig is null?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a conditional expression in your **[`$sum`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sum/#grp._S_sum)** operator that will check if the `"$virustotal.results.sig"` key is null by using the comparison operator **[`$gt`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/gt/#exp._S_gt)** (as specified in the [documentation's BSON comparsion order](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/bson-types/#bson-types-comparison-order))

You can restructure your pipeline by adding this expression as follows:

```
db.analysis.aggregate([
    { "$unwind": "$virustotal.results" },
    {
        "$group" : {
            "_id": "$virustotal.results.vendor", 
            "count" : { 
                "$sum": {
                    "$cond": [
                        { "$gt": [ "$virustotal.results.sig", null ] },
                        1, 0
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    },
    { "$sort" : { "count" : -1 } }
])
```

**Sample Output**

```
/* 1 */
{
    "_id" : "Qihoo-360",
    "count" : 2
}

/* 2 */
{
    "_id" : "MicroWorld-eScan",
    "count" : 1
}

/* 3 */
{
    "_id" : "Bkav",
    "count" : 0
}

/* 4 */
{
    "_id" : "CAT-QuickHeal",
    "count" : 0
}

/* 5 */
{
    "_id" : "nProtect",
    "count" : 0
}

/* 6 */
{
    "_id" : "ahnlab",
    "count" : 0
}
```

Comment: I see.
I was simply clicking over the up arrow "answer useful" but due I have low reputation, the changes is not shown :(
Let me know if now is ok :)

Comment: @MarioArancioni That's fine now :) Thank you

Comment: Hello, didn't know if open another thread or continuing here. The code is working in mongo shell, now I'm translating in python:
        vt_list = results_db.analysis.aggregate( [ { "$unwind": "$virustotal.results" },{"$group": { "_id":"$virustotal.results.vendor","count": { "$sum": { "$cond": [ { "$gt": [ "$virustotal.results.sig","null" ] } ,1,0 ] } } } },{ "$sort": { "count" : -1 } } ] )

    for vt in vt_list:
        report["states_count"][vt["_id"]] = vt["count"]

The query is returning not ordered values and most important wrong count! (less)

Do you have any idea?

Comment: Just change this line `{ "$gt": [ "$virustotal.results.sig", "null" ] }` to `{ "$gt": [ "$virustotal.results.sig", None ] }`

Comment: I would suggest create another question, tagging `pymongo` as well as showing your expected output with the aggregation pipeline.

Answer (score 0):

I changed the null with None and the numbers increased but seems not correct yet.
Basically doing the query in mongoshell I get like

{
    "_id" : "Kaspersky",
    "count" : 176.0
    }

from python:
Kaspersky   64

one of these 2 is wrong :)

So I'm trying to investigate what part of the query in python is not correctly written compared to the mongo shell one.
I did a simple query:
In mongoshell:
        rtmp = results_db.analysis.count( { "virustotal.results" : { "$elemMatch" : { "vendor": "Kaspersky", "sig": {"$ne": "null"} } }})
results: 176

db.analysis.count( { "virustotal.results" : { $elemMatch : { "vendor": "Kaspersky", "sig": {$gt: null} } }})
results: 0

Then I tried in python:
    rtmp = results_db.analysis.count( { "virustotal.results" : { "$elemMatch" : { "vendor": "Kaspersky", "sig": {"$ne": "null"} } }})
results: 568

```
rtmp = results_db.analysis.count( { "virustotal.results" : { "$elemMatch" : { "vendor": "Kaspersky", "sig": {"$ne": "None"} } }})
```

results: 568

```
rtmp = results_db.analysis.count( { "virustotal.results" : { "$elemMatch" : { "vendor": "Kaspersky", "sig": {"$gt": "None"} } }})
```

results: 64

```
rtmp = results_db.analysis.count( { "virustotal.results" : { "$elemMatch" : { "vendor": "Kaspersky", "sig": {"$gt": "null"} } }})
```

results: 6

hard to says what is the correct value! I suppose 176 but not able to reproduce in python...